# Using Symfony4 form component Standalone with Twig and Form Extension

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

I'm setting up an environment that use some of the symfony components as a base.

I would like to use Form component as the form manager of the application with Twig for template. I install: form, twig and twig_bridge

Because I have this limited set of components I have registered a RuntimeLoader class on Twig to manage the Form extension dependency over the FormRenderer.

After setting up a simple test with a basic form as explained in the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html I get this error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("No block "form_start" found while rendering the form.").
```

All my work starts here:

```
 //templating index.php
 $twigLoader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem( getcwd() . '/Templates' );
 $twig = new \Twig_Environment( $twigLoader );
 $twig->addRuntimeLoader( new RuntimeLoader( $twig ) );
 $twig->addExtension( new FormExtension() );
```

The RuntimeLoader is similar to the one explained on the twig docs: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#creating-an-extension 
This is used to honor the dependency of the FormExtension nodes over the FormRenderer class (Symfony Framework use a service for this)

```
namespace Forge\UI;

use Twig\RuntimeLoader\RuntimeLoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRendererEngine;

class RuntimeLoader implements RuntimeLoaderInterface {

 private $twig;

 public function __construct( $twig ) {
  $this->twig = $twig;
 }

 public function load( $class ) {
  //var_dump( $class );
  if ( 'Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer' === $class ) {
   return new $class( new TwigRendererEngine( [ 'form.html.twig' ], $this->twig )     );
  }
 }
}
```

Then after all in a controller class I call all the soup:

```
  $task = new Task();
  $task->setTask( 'Make somebody happy' );

  $form = $this->createFormBuilder( $task )
   ->add( 'task', TextType::class )
   ->add( 'save', SubmitType::class, [ 'label' => 'Create Task' ] )->getForm();

  $content = $this->renderView( 'form.html.twig', [ 'form'=>$form->createView() ] );
```

This throw an Error:

```
object(Twig_Error_Runtime)#258 (12) {
  ["lineno":"Twig_Error":private]=>
  int(1)
  ["name":"Twig_Error":private]=>
  string(14) "form.html.twig"
  ["rawMessage":"Twig_Error":private]=>
  string(122) "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("No block "form_start" found while rendering the form.")."
  ["sourcePath":"Twig_Error":private]=>
  string(58) "/var/www/../Templates/form.html.twig"
  ["sourceCode":"Twig_Error":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["message":protected]=>
   string(122) "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("No block "form_start" found while rendering the form.")."
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["file":protected]=>
   string(58) "/var/www/../Templates/form.html.twig"
  ["line":protected]=>
  int(1)
```

the source path of the error is a simple twig template:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

How do I get rid of the exception?
P.s. I don't want to install all the symfony packages.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to follow the [form component templating](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#twig-templating) docs for configuration.  It is easy to mix up the component docs with the framework docs.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I had not seen that page. I solve my problem but this cost other 3 components required (config, translation, filesystem).

Comment: Yep.  By the time you get everything to play nice together you have basically re-implemented the framework bundle.

Comment: It's a long know "issue": The form component is one of the deepest coupled components in the framework.

Comment: Find a working Example here: https://php.budgegeria.de/sbez1

Comment: if one really wants to tackle this I found out that you can now use twig-bridge from the symfony repo to achieve this result, unfortunatelly it requires you to use HttpFoundation /session to enable Csrf protection on the form, which is not psr17 compliant afaik